# How to find product data on the front-end of an X-Cart page

Tags: javascript, x-cart

Is there a way to reliably find product data on the front-end of an X-Cart page?

Templates tend to differ greatly in how they present products or carts, so HTML scraping is not an option.

Is there no global Javascript variable that contains that info (like there is on other web shop platforms)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that **there's no such a global JS variable**

The long answer is that it's possible to find a workaround, but here in X-Cart team we need more details to help with the exact solution, so let's move the further discussion to the forum where you have already posted your question too.